# IntelliJ IDEA, turn off insertion of 'final' keyword before instance variables on format/save (JAVA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, final

I cannot for the life of me find out where I can turn off insertion of the 'final' keyword on instance variables in IntelliJ IDEA.

Basically IntelliJ is checking to see if a instance field is being assigned to and if it isn't its automatically making it final. This wouldn't be a problem usually but I am doing serialization and it is presenting problems.

As a reference (I declare):

```
 private HashSet<Integer> removedIndex = new HashSet<>();
```

IntelliJ makes it:

```
private final HashSet<Integer> removedIndex = new HashSet<>();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using the [Save Actions Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions)? ... Look for a "Save Actions" entry under `Preferences > Other Settings`.

Comment: Aha, yes that is it. Thanks! If you write this as answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using the [Save Actions Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions). To disable this behaviour ...

- `Preferences > Other Settings > Save Actions`
- Untick `Add final to field`